# How to adjust weight sum for horizontal gap between relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have one Framelayout  inside that i have Linealayout whose weightSum 5.1 inside there we have 5 layout i want to adjust horizontal gap each based one some  ratio (27:51:48:48:48:24) from left to right so that it should but its not fixing. how to fix it?

i tried with layout_weight `1,.9,.9,.8,1` but its not fixing
 that ratio but UI its not fixing my  horizontal gap ratio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bb_bottom_bar_outer_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/float_common"
    android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_updatenow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5.1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_layout_home"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="2dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/float_image_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6"
                android:background="@drawable/float_home__new_click" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/float_text_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_7"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.05"
                android:text="@string/home"
                android:textColor="@color/text_mid_grey" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_layout_collect"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="2dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/float_image_collect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6"
                android:background="@drawable/float_collect_new_click" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/float_text_collect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_7"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.05"

                android:text="@string/collect_tab_title"
                android:textColor="@color/text_mid_grey" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_layout_offers"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="2dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/float_offers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6"
                android:background="@drawable/float_offercoupons_new_click" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_badge"
                style="@style/Typeface.Footnote.White"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/float_offers"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/float_text_offers"
                style="@style/Typeface.Small.TextMidGrey"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_7"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.05"
                 />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_layout_voucher"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/float_voucher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6"
                android:background="@drawable/float_myimage_new_click" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/float_text_voucher"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_7"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.05"
                android:text="@string/vouchers"
                android:textColor="@color/text_mid_grey" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_layout_boost"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/float_boost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6"
                android:background="@drawable/float_image2_new_click" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/float_text_boost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_7"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.05"
                android:text="@string/boost"
                android:textColor="@color/text_mid_grey" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I want keep  horizontal ratio so that my UI should like like below screen

[image]

Comment: the attribute "android:weightSum" is used to set the total weight. so if you provide this in the parent linear layout, then its child view's weights should sum up to the provided weightSum.

Comment: yes i tried with same but unable to get the result as i show you in attached screen shot  could you please suggest?

Comment: here your child view's total weight is 4.6 and you have given weightSum as 5.1. that is why your view is not fitting as expected.

Comment: so if i will apply 4.6 then will it work ?

Comment: if you set it as 4.6, then your view will fit to full width.

Comment: Thanks wait let me check  and let  you know but how about ratio can you please suggest me how we can maintain ratio . @ViswasKg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191950/discussion-between-marsh-and-viswas-kg).

Comment: @ViswasKg could you please  https://pasteboard.co/IauIGwg.png  i want keep  horizontal  spacing   like this

Comment: @ViswasKg could you please help me in this still am facing same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your weight, but you will face another problem you say that your relative layout take a weight for width but inside you put wrap content on your element.

This is an exemple if your total width is 1000dp and you put a weight on an element inside your container, let's say the width of your element is 100dp with the calculated weight but your image take 120dp with wrap_content, did you see the problems ?

Let me show you this little solution I wrote

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="246">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="27" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="51" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="48" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="48" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="48" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="24" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In this code the weight are only on the space between element exactly like your drawing every element between space can wrap his content

Comment: Thanks for reply  let me  check .

Comment: using this code i am unable to see image and text . @Vodet

Comment: Did you add android:text and image src for ImageView ?

Comment: I have added  android:background="@drawable/float_home__new_click"  neither text nor image is displaying in top i have use frame layout @Vodet

Comment: For you image you need to put your height and width instead of wrap_content

Comment: Then also its no coming even text should right that also its not coming

Comment: could you please help me in this issue because i am still facing issue in this?

Comment: did you try to change the image width and height with the size you want and set the src

Comment: yes i tried but  middle item not coming getting collapse and become hide only one line visible @Vodet Cupons & Offer